# Помогите разобраться с ошибкой в запросе SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Делаю два запроса:

```
CREATE TABLE `config`(
 `serverid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `parameter` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `value1` text,
 `value2` text
 )

INSERT INTO config (`serverid`, `parameter`, `value1`, `value2`) VALUES ('234234', 'warning', '4', 'ban')
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO config (`serverid`, `parameter`, `value1`, `value2`) VALUES ('234234', 'warn' at line 8
```

Всем заранее спасибо!

P.S. Запросы делаются раздельно. Написал их как один, что бы было ясно структуру таблицы.

Comment: Запросы должны завершаться текущим терминатором. По умолчанию - точка с запятой `;`.

Comment: У меня запросы выполняются по отдельности. Написал их как один, что бы было ясно структуру таблицы

Comment: Вот [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/). Там на каждой второй странице есть хотя бы один запрос. И все они (АБСОЛЮТНО ВСЕ !!!) завершаются точкой с запятой, либо иным символом/подстрокой, если в том же блоке кода delimiter был переопределён. И если даже там никто не позволил себе пропускать этот символ - то Вы можете даже не рассчитывать, что "прокатит".

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы пишите названия столбцов в одинарных кавычках. Попробуйте обойтись без них. При этом, если вы вставляете значения во все столбцы, можно обойтись без перечислений всех столбцов.
Вот пример команды:
http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_operator_insert.html

P.S.

Предвосхищая еще вопрос, сразу скажу: все равно не получается из-за того, что цифровые значения вы передаете как строки в кавычках. Обратите больше внимания на синтаксис.

Answer (score 0):

У меня ощущение, что проблема не в самом запросе, а в том, откуда вы его запускаете.

Я сейчас попробовал на локальном MariaDB через adminer запустить ваш запрос, все работает. И дело не в отсутствии ;.

Обратите внимание, возможно ваш фреймворк или через что вы отправляете запрос, обрезает строку, если обратить внимание - в ошибке строка запроса показана не полностью и возможно это и есть причина ошибки.